# How to initialize weights in the model function of a TensorFlow estimator, using pre-trained variables?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I want to wrap my model using the tf.Estimator API of TensorFlow, so I have the following `model_fn`:

```
    def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
        # Load vocabulary
        n_vocab = params['n_vocab']

        if mode != tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
            labels = tf.reshape(labels, (-1, 1))

        embedding = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((tf.cast(n_vocab, tf.int32),
                                                  tf.cast(params['embed_space'], tf.int32)), 0, 1), name='embedding')
        embedding_layer = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, features[INPUT_TENSOR_NAME], name='embedding_layer')

        ...
```

It initializes the embedding variables and does some other things down the line. Now, I do not want to initialize those weights using `tf.random_uniform`, but use the weight from a saved model I have trained before, and freeze them so they are not trainable. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tf.estimator.WarmStartSettings`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/WarmStartSettings). Estimator provides an easy way to create this by adding an argument called `warm_start_from`.

When creating the estimator, you should pass the saved model directory:

```
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn, model_dir, warm_start_from=SAVED_MODEL_DIR)
```

Just a note, you may need the unfrozen version of the saved model.

Comment: even before starting the training using `
tf.estimator.LinearRegressor`, we need to initialize the weights for our defined model, which API in tensorflow does that? Could you point me to it? It could be the case that tf is doing by itself, but how and from where?. Thanks for giving an answer where to load the pre-trained weight, but from where tf initiate in the 1st run isn't clear.